# Unable to trigger email using SES in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, amazon-vpc

As part of my learning aws i am trying to send email using SES. I have a lambda which will do this for me and this lambda is part of a private subnet. This private subnet has a security group which has smtp and smtps inbound rules set to the security group mentioned above. Everytime i update the lambda configuration and assign it a private subnet, the request to SES.senEmail gets timed out. If this lambda is not part of vpc, then everything works fine. Based on online search, either i am missing IAM roles, which i am not as the lambda IAM has full access to SES and SESv2. Any help in this direction would be useful. Is there any other approach to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

A Lambda function in a VPC does not get a public IP address, so it will not have access to any resources that exist outside the VPC. To fix this your private subnet needs to have a route to a NAT Gateway.

Alternatively, you could [setup an SES endpoint in the VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html).